# django registration redux not redirecting to base.html after login

Tags: python, django, url

I am working on a e-comm application, I am using django registration redux to setup user registration and login. Initially when I set up the register/login system it was working fine..when I put bootstrap and styles in my base.html, the functionality broke and after user login rather it redirecting to base.html..it tries to fetch http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/, this url..

I can't seem to figure out the reason.

Here is my settings.py
Also to note, when I put 'store' at the last in Installed apps section and try to click login/register url comes back to base.html rather than login/register pages.

"""

```
Django settings for bookstore project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/



# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'store',
    'registration',
    'bootstrap3',
    'bootstrap_themes',

)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'bookstore.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'bookstore.wsgi.application'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
)

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


# Registration

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/store/"
```

base.html

```
{% extends 'bootstrap3/bootstrap3.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% load bootstrap_themes %}
{% bootstrap_styles theme='simplex' type='min.css' %}

{% block bootstrap3_extra_head %}

<link href = "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href = "{% static 'base/css/style.css' %}" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
{% endblock %}


        {% block bootstrap3_title %}
        {% block title %}
            Welcome to Pick A Book !!
        {% endblock %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block bootstrap3_content %}

     <nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class ="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target = "#navbar">
                <span class = "icon-bar"> </span>
                 <span class = "icon-bar"> </span>
                 <span class = "icon-bar"> </span>
            </button>
            <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="navbar-brand">Pick A Book </a>
        </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="hvr-curl-top-right"><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a></li>
                <li class="hvr-curl-top-right"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li class="hvr-curl-top-right"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
             </ul>
             <div class="navbar-form pull-right">
                {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                    Welcome, {% if request.user.first_name %}
                    {{ request.user.first_name}}
                    {% else %}
                    {{ request.user.username  }}
                    {% endif %}! <a href="(% url 'auth_logout' %}"> Log Out</a>
                {% else %}
                     Welcome, mysterious person! <a href="{% url 'auth_login' %}">Log In? </a> or <a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">Register</a>
                {% endif %}
             </div>
          </div>
         </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <img src="{% static 'base/img/header_full.jpg' %}" class ="bg">
      <div class="parallax">
        <div class="row">
         {% block body %}
         <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12 maincontent">
           Welcome to our store!
         </div>
         {% endblock %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center navbar footer">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>  2017 Pick A Book. Developed by  <a href="http://kshitijrangai.com"> Kshitij Rangari </a> </p>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'bookstore.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url (r'^store/', include('store.urls'), name='store'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url ('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace = 'social')),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to base.html you have to make a little change in setting.py

just add **LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'base_url'**

Hope it works